# where in android phone app error log?

Tags: android, logging, alarmmanager

Which sets the date of the call activity.
I use alarm manager and button click.

Activity
    package com.example.nn.gallery;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class SettingsPanel extends Activity {

    Long time;

    Button button;

    public static final String ALARM_TIME_HOUR   = "alarm_time_hour";

    public static final String ALARM_TIME_MINUTES = "alarm_time_minets";

    public static final String ALARM_NOTIFICATION_SECONDS = "alarm_notification_seconds";

    TimePicker timePicker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_panel);

        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveDate);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //вычислить время запуска
                //установить alarm

                int hour    = timePicker.getHour();
                int minutes = timePicker.getMinute();

                long acrossTimeMs = getAlarmTime(hour,minutes);

                //System.out.println(acrossTimeMs);

                //savePickerTime(hour,minutes,acrossTimeMs);

                restartAlarm(acrossTimeMs);

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param hour
     * @param minutes
     */
    public void savePickerTime(int hour,int minutes,long accrosTime) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt(ALARM_TIME_HOUR,hour);
        editor.putInt(ALARM_TIME_MINUTES,minutes);
        editor.putLong(ALARM_NOTIFICATION_SECONDS,accrosTime);

        editor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Notification time saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * setAlarmTime
     * @param alarmTime ms unixtime
     */
    public void restartAlarm(long alarmTime){

        AlarmManager alarmManager   = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent               = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);

    }

    /**
     * Нow many minutes will call
     *
     * @param pickerHour
     * @param pickerMinutes
     * @return long millseconds
     */
    public long getAlarmTime(int pickerHour,int pickerMinutes){
        Calendar c         = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentHour    = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int currentMinutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        //System.out.println("current " + currentHour + " " +  currentMinutes);
        //System.out.println("picker " + pickerHour + " " + pickerMinutes);

        //System.out.println((currentHour * 60) + currentMinutes);
        //System.out.println((pickerHour * 60) + pickerMinutes);

        boolean currentTimeMore = ((currentHour * 60) + currentMinutes) >  ((pickerHour * 60) + pickerMinutes);

        //System.out.println( ((currentHour * 60) + currentMinutes) + " " +  ((pickerHour * 60) + pickerMinutes));

        int across;

        if(currentTimeMore){
            across = (24 * 60 )- ((currentHour * 60) + currentMinutes) + ((pickerHour * 60) + pickerMinutes);
        }else {
            across = (((pickerHour * 60) + pickerMinutes) - ((currentHour * 60) + currentMinutes));
        }

        long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


        //across = unixTime + (across * 60);

        long acrossLong = unixTime + (across * 60 * 1000);

        return acrossLong;
        //System.out.println(across + " across minets");

        //System.out.println(timeEcuals);

        //получить текущь время
        //получить время пикера

        //вернуть лонг милисекунды
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver

```
package com.example.nn.gallery;

/**
 * Created by nn on 6/2/16.
 */
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class AlarmReceiver extends  BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Intent i = new Intent();
       i.setClassName("com.example.nn.gallery", "com.example.nn.gallery.CallCamera");
       i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

Layout

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_settings_panel" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nn.gallery">


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsPanel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings_panel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />

        <activity android:name=".CallCamera"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How i can see error logs on phone?
Emulator does not produce errors on your computer.

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ez7w9ug_0Kk this video(on Russian) describe how to use logcat on AndroidStudio or Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en) or any alternative to read the stacktrace